# the size of a png image

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, memory-management

The exception is `Unhandled exception at 0x770CAE54 (ntdll.dll) in OpenCVPaint.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x770DFE38).` There's a **Corruption in the heap**, because I write to a place I shouldn't (I didn't allocate enough room). But how come I write to a place I shouldn't?

I fixed it partially, I changed `my_pic.create()` rows and cols in the code so it'd suffice I guess. But why did I need to? Why does it go wrong with `h` as 67 and `w` as 73 (exactly what it's supposed to need)? How much memory does it need if not `67(HEIGHT)x73(WIDTH)x3(RGB)`?

- If I change the type (currently `CV_8UC3` it works but the image captured is far from accurate) instead of the creating line, it works too.
- bmi.biImageSize` is calculate to be 67, why? does that cause the problem?

The code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace cv;

Mat screenCapture()
{
        HDC hdcSource = GetDC(NULL);
        HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSource);


    Mat my_pic;
    int i, j;
    int w, h;
    POINT p1, p2; //Windows.h

    p1.x = 437;
    p1.y = 247;
    p2.x = 510;
    p2.y = 314;

    w = p2.x - p1.x;
    h = p2.y - p1.y;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSource, w, h);
    HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.biBitCount = 24;

    bmi.biWidth = w;
    bmi.biHeight = -h;
    bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    bmi.biSizeImage = ((bmi.biWidth * bmi.biBitCount + 31) & ~31) / 8 * bmi.biHeight<0 ? -bmi.biHeight : bmi.biHeight;
    bmi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmi.biClrImportant = 0;
    bmi.biClrUsed = 256;

    while (!(BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, w, h, hdcSource, p1.x, p1.y, SRCCOPY)));

    while (!(hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld)));

    my_pic.create(h, w, CV_8UC3); //THE PROBLEM IS HERE, NOT ENOUGH ALLOCATED

    while (!(GetDIBits(hdcSource, hBitmap, 0, h, my_pic.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS)));

    DeleteDC(hdcSource);
    DeleteDC(hdcMemory);

    return my_pic;
}

int main()
{
    Mat img = screenCapture();
    malloc(0); //exception occurs here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It'd be much appreciated if you'd mention the reason of why you down-vote this question.

Comment: It's downvoted because you did not provide code to reproduce your problem. I didn't do it, but most people who want to help also want to see a runnable example.

Comment: Please post some [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.  And I did down vote.  Will undo the down vote back if you do this.

Comment: I vote to close - unclear, no code, etc...

Comment: I added the minimal code that is needed to cause the error on my machine, please remove your downvotes.

Comment: Took back my down vote.  Possibly not MCVE at all but at least you made an effort - and it *is* Christmas after all :) )

Comment: @Jim So 1) Why are you using `while` loops for those functions?  2) Why is there no error checking (i.e. getting return code and calling `GetLastError`) to check for failure?

Comment: @JerryCoffin You can execute it on your machine, copy and paste the code, compile and execute.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1) Because sometimes it fails the first or the second time (especially `GetDIBits`), but the exception occurs even if they don't fail a single time. 2)It doesn't seem to be cause by an error, so I removed these parts when posting it here.

Comment: As match as I know `malloc()` does not throw exception when there is no memory (it is C function first of all), what kind of exception do you get?

Comment: @Jim *Because sometimes it fails the first or the second time* -- And the reason for the failure is ..... That's why you need to implement `GetLastError` and optional `FormatMessage`, so that you know why the failure occurs and not just ignore it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It doesn't seem like I can reproduce a problem with both of these, so even removing the looping won't matter as they all succeed (return values are valid).

Comment: @Jim Did you check that you're sending the correct parameter values to `GetDIBits`, especially the `my_pic.data` parameter?  According to the docs, this has to be NULL or already sized correctly to retrieve the data.  Maybe the buffer is too small and an overwrite occurs?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Slava As I debug, one of the function it calls calls a function that calls `__heap__alloc()`, and the exception occurs there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I executed the code a couple hours ago and it worked perfectly, so the problem shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Jim You could have executed the program a few days ago -- it doesn't matter.  If you overwrite memory, the behavior of the program becomes undefined.  Thus your new *EDIT* you put into the post doesn't really mean anything.  Buggy programs can run seemingly without error on one machine, and crash on another.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I re-confirmed, yes, the parameters are valid.

Comment: @Jim Also, I suggest you don't do anything to "disturb the error".  Make sure that the error is reproducible so that it can properly be diagnosed and fixed.  Turning off/on your machine, reinstalling Visual Studio, etc. will not fix your error, even if you see that it doesn't appear after doing these steps.  Those steps are just fool's gold.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I restarted. Nothing new, same exception thrown.

Comment: @Jim *I loop through certain function calls until they succeed* -- I still think you need to do more investigating here.  You can't just ignore these functions if they fail.  They fail for a reason, and that reason can be (or at least give an idea) of the issue by calling `GetLastError`.  The Windows GDI is not erratic in that you expect failures to occur and thus go into a "retry" loop.  If that function fails once, you need to know why.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I ran it over 50 times now and no error happened, I did modify the code on my machine to print on failure but they didn't fail up to now.

Comment: @Jim - ok.  However you should leave the error checking in the function.  You never know when the problem may arise again.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes. Read the post again, though. I recognized the problem but I don't know why is it exactly happening.

Comment: @Jim Look at your calculation to compute the image size in the `BITMAPINFO::biSizeImage`.  From what I remember, that calculation is done to consider word alignment of the image.  Please inspect that value and compare it to the number of bytes you're allocating in the `create` function.  Maybe this is where the extra bytes come from that you are missing from the `create` function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right. What should the size be though?

Comment: @Jim Just a guess, but you probably will need to make sure that the width of the image is evenly divisible by 4 (on a word boundary). So for example, if the image width is 890, the actual width you should allocate in the create function should be 892 . My experience is that images that have widths that are not divisible by 4 either have a staircase effect when displayed or as in your case, not enough memory was allocated to process the image, and the fix is to make the width of the image align on a WORD boundary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, this was it :D Thank you so much, you might want to post it as an answer

Comment: @Jim -- Added the answer and link to the information concerning DWORD alignment of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [GetDIBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function requires that images have scan lines that have widths that are DWORD aligned (must be a multiple of `sizeof(DWORD)`, which is `4` for a Window's DIB).  From the link:

***The scan lines must be aligned on a DWORD except for RLE compressed bitmaps.***

Since the original image has a width that is not aligned, it is the responsibility of the application to force alignment by adjusting the width calculation.

When an image is not aligned, and no provisions are made by the application to align the image, what usually ends up happening is either:

1) The image is displayed, but has a "staircase" effect, where each scan line of the displayed image seems to be off by a certain amount or,

2) Not enough memory is allocated to process the image, and thus heap errors may occur.

The issue seems to be that not enough memory was allocated for the image in the `create` function to match the extra bytes required for the alignment adjustment.  So for example, if the width is 437, the actual width used in the calculation for the amount of memory to allocate should be based on a width of 440, not 437.